# logger error when using ejabberd embedded in Elixir app

Tags: elixir, ejabberd

I followed tutorial on https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/extending-ejabberd/elixir/ to use Ejabberd embedded in elixir app.

When started, ejabber writes, that it will use elixir logger:

14:43:24.485 [info] Ignoring ejabberd logger options, using Elixir Logger.

However, then I got many errors like:

```
14:43:25.987 [error] :gen_event handler :elixir_logger_backend installed in :lager_event terminating
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Logger.Config.__data__/0 is undefined or private
    (logger) Logger.Config.__data__()
    (ejabberd) src/elixir_logger_backend.erl:43: :elixir_logger_backend.handle_event/2
    (stdlib) gen_event.erl:577: :gen_event.server_update/4
    (stdlib) gen_event.erl:559: :gen_event.server_notify/4
    (stdlib) gen_event.erl:300: :gen_event.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I have configured logger in confix.exs:

```
config :logger,
  backends: [:console]
```

And also tried to start logger in mix.exs:

```
def application do
    [
       extra_applications: [:logger]
    ]
  end
```

Any idea how to fix those errors?

Answer (score 3):

You probably should downgrade your [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) version. For instance, in `v1.0` there was undocumented function [`Logger.Config.__data__/0`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.0/lib/logger/lib/logger/config.ex#L48-L60) that was later removed, but `ejabberd` for some reason relied on its existence.

I have no idea what version it was presented last, but you could easily discover that by changing versions in GH interface.

Other option would be to use an internal / erlang logger, it should work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, this function was removed in Elixir 1.9.